# Null object when passing value from textArea inside Foreach to OnPost (object is IEnumerable)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mvvm, razor-pages

I have the following CSHTML class:

```
@model WorkInProgress.Pages.Expenditures
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class = text-start>Task Number</th>
    <th class = text-start>Expenditure Type</th>
    <th class = text-end>Item Date</th>
    <th class = text-end>Billable</th>
    <th class = text-end>Vendor Id</th>
    <th></th>
    <th class = text-start>Vendor Name</th>
    <th class = text-end>Revenue Amount</th>
    <th class = text-end>Comments</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

@foreach (var expenditure in Model.ExpendituresList)
{
    <tr>
        <td class = text-start>@expenditure.TaskNumber</td>
        <td class = text-start>@expenditure.ExpenditureType</td>
        <td class = text-end>@expenditure.ExpenditureItemDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")</td>
        <td class = text-end>@expenditure.BillableFlag</td>
        <td class = text-end>@expenditure.VendorId</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class = text-start>@expenditure.SupplierName</td>
        <td class = text-end>@expenditure.ProjFuncRevenueAmount</td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => expenditure.ExpenditureItemId)
        <td class=text-end>
            <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.ExpendituresList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ExpenditureItemId == expenditure.ExpenditureItemId)!.ExpenditureComment"  rows="1"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
<div class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-page-handler="Button">Save</button></div>
```

in which I'm trying to have something like this:

[image]

and then from there, capture the text in the textArea and send it to the Post with the value for the textArea (that I want to put in `expenditure.ExpenditureComment`

the class that fills the expenditures is

```
 [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]  
        public IEnumerable<Expenditure> ExpendituresList { get; set; }
```

with the properties for    `public decimal ExpenditureItemId { get; set; }` and `public string? ExpenditureComment { get; set; }`

however when debbugging the OnPost after clicking "Save" the object ExpenditureList returns empty.

I think my issue is in the way I'm setting the `<TextArea>` element. but I've been trying different setups and not being able to make it work

Comment: Seems like it should be <textarea asp-for="Model.ExpendituresList[x].ExpenditureComment"...  You'll want to use a for loop with x as the iterator... so  @for (var x = 0; x < Model.ExpendituresList.Count(); x++)
            { ...  }   use Model.ExpenditureList[x] for each item.  (instead of foreach)

Comment: @Baldie47 Did you have any progress? Or any other questions?

Comment: Hello @TinyWang sorry I was away for a few days, I have tried to set with your solution; it does makes perfectly sense, and with the for I'm getting it to load the data to the screen, but when I click the Save button the object goes null again. I'm trying to figure out if it's something to do with me using the same Save button in other sections (if I need to specify the textArea as part of the same form for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @pcalkins, and since you need to post  all rows in the table, so you need to make sure each line of the `<textarea>` have the unique name to make sure all the rows can be submit, so you have to use `@for` instead of `@foreach`.

I did a test in my side and pls note I defined `List<Expenditures>` instead of `IEnumerable`

```
public class Expenditures
{
    public int ExpenditureItemId { get; set; }
    public string? ExpenditureComment { get; set; }
}

public class ViewMode {
    public List<Expenditures> ExpendituresList { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my page:

```
@model ViewMode
<form method="post" asp-action="saveData">
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class = text-start>Task Number</th>
        <th class = text-end>Comments</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @for (var x = 0; x < Model.ExpendituresList.Count(); x++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class = text-start asp-for="@Model.ExpendituresList[x].ExpenditureItemId">@Model.ExpendituresList[x].ExpenditureItemId</td>
            <td class=text-end>
                <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.ExpendituresList[x].ExpenditureComment"  rows="1"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

This is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void saveData( ViewMode vms)
    {
        var a = vms;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: by doing it this way, I do get all data populated, however when I click the Save button it only passes the comment to the post, all the rest of the object gets nulled. the object is marked as [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]]

Comment: `all the rest of the object gets nulled` it should be the expected behavior if you didn't change other code, since we were using form submit to post data to your controller, it will package all the [form elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) as the parameter..In the other word, if you want to submit `id` as well, then you need to write code like `<td><input type="text" value="id" asp-for="@Model.ExpendituresList[x].ExpenditureItemId"></input></td>`.